# Can Not Create Planner Plan duo lack of permission

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create **Planner Plan** using Microsoft Graph API. As [documented](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/planner_post_plans) it requires `groupId`. I also create Group, but when i create a Planner plan using Graph Explore it returns a `403` with the message

> "You do not have the required permissions to access this item, or the item may not exist."

I'm aware that in order to create a plan, It required `Group.ReadWrite.All` permission on `Delegated (work or school account)`. I granted these in the Azure Portal but still get same error.

One thing is I don't know how to determine if my account is a "work or school account". My account was created by the admin of my tenant and it uses the of my organization so I guest it is Work account.

What do I have wrong here, do I need another API to assign plan to group before create?

## EDIT1:

Here is the request body when i'm create a Planner Group, I'm also tried to toggle "securityEnabled" to true but it still fail when create a plan

[image]

And Here is the Request body when I create Planner Plan

[image: Create Planner Groups]

## EDIT2:

I also tried to update Planner plan by [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/plannerplandetails_update) API and it still failed. It seems `Group.ReadWrite.All` permissions does not apply to my account

Comment: Can you add the URL and POST Body you're sending to the API?

Comment: Hi @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I've add the Picture to describe more about my problems. Please take a look at this

Comment: Anyone know the issues?

Comment: Likely a silly question but have you confirmed that this permission is selected in Graph Explorer? Remember that consent is by tenant and app so you need a consent for Graph Explorer from the admin of the AD you're connecting too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your request is failing because you are not a member of the group in which you are trying to create a plan. Changing group content requires the calling user to be a member. Owners of the group currently cannot edit the Planner content in the group, unless they are also members.

Comment: its work, you're my life saver. When i create a group, I'm also be an owner of the group. I thought i can create a plan if i already an owner. thank you ^^!

Answer (score 1):

Although you have requested `Group.ReadWrite.All`, you cannot authorize this permission until you have received "Consent" from an Administrator.

If you're using the Azure Portal to register you app (aka the v1 Endpoint) then your admin can either use the Admin Consent workflow or directly grant permission within the portal. You can read more about he Consent Framework in [Integrating applications with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications#overview-of-the-consent-framework).

Comment: I'm aware of this. After add the `Group.ReadWrite.All`, I clicked grant permission on the azure portal. As i understand, when i click `Grant Permission` button on azure portal, users of my tenant don't need to consent again when i add new permisison. I have tried and still failed when create a plan

Comment: You do need to reconsent whenever you add additional permissions. You've only consented to what was originally requested. Otherwise any app dev could just switch out permissions without you knowing.

Comment: I tried to reconsent but it still not working. Anyway to detect what permission i missed